# Expected a more extensive RTL Viewer

Tags: vhdl, register-transfer-level

I synthesized my VHDL code. When I saw the RTL viewer, I was expecting another outcome. I got a state machine build with VHDL code (see below) and got the following outcome (see picture). Some things that I don't get here:

- What does `1'h0` mean?
- What does `state~7` mean?
- Why is there only one block `state`? Where are the other states?

**VHDL Code:**

```
ENTITY state_machine IS
PORT (  clk: IN std_logic;
        reset: IN std_logic;
        X: IN BIT;
        Z: OUT BIT);
END state_machine;

--  Present State   Next State      Output
--                  X       !X
--                                  Z
--  S0              S0      S1      0
--  S1              S0      S11     0
--  S11             S110    S11     0
--  S110            S0      S1101   0
--  S1101           S0      S11     1

ARCHITECTURE behaviour OF state_machine IS
  TYPE states IS (S0, S1, S11, S110, S1101);    
  SIGNAL state : states;                        
BEGIN

next_state : PROCESS(reset, clk)    
BEGIN
    IF reset='0' THEN
        state <= S0;
    ELSIF rising_edge(clk) THEN
        CASE state IS
            WHEN S0 => 
                IF X='0' THEN 
                    state<=S1; 
                END IF;
            WHEN S1 => 
                IF X='0' THEN
                    state<=S11; 
                ELSE 
                    state<=S0;
                END IF;
            WHEN S11 => 
                IF X='0' THEN
                    state<=S11; 
                ELSE 
                    state<=S110;
                END IF;
            WHEN S110 => 
                IF X='0' THEN
                    state<=S1101; 
                ELSE 
                    state<=S0;
                END IF;
            WHEN S1101 => 
                IF X='0' THEN
                    state<=S11; 
                ELSE 
                    state<=S0;
                END IF;
        END CASE;
    END IF;
END PROCESS;

output:PROCESS(state)
BEGIN
    CASE state IS
        WHEN S0 => Z<='0';
        WHEN S1 => Z<='0';
        WHEN S11 => Z<='0';
        WHEN S110 => Z<='0';
        WHEN S1101 => Z<='1';
    END CASE;
END PROCESS;
END behaviour;
```

**RTL Schematic:**

[image: RTL Viewer]

Comment: Is there some hierarchy? Logic synthesisers know about state machines. Yours would have recognised your code as being a state machine. Is perhaps the yellow box a lower level with some more logic inside?

Comment: `1'h0` is probably Verilog. It means a 1-bit wide hexadecimal literal with value 0. So, for example, `4'hF` would be `X"F"` or `"1111"` in VHDL.

Comment: There's probably a tag for the particular vendor's tool. The added tag might add value to those using Stackoverflow as a resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The viewer uses Verilog notation for constants, and `1'h0` in Verilog is the same as `'0'` in VHDL.

The OR-gate is simply named `state~7`, just like the yellow box is named `state`.  So the OR-gate is simply an inverter so the reset to `state` block is `not reset` for the external reset input.

The rest of the design with the state machine is put in an internal block named `state`, so if you double click on this it will probably expand.  The `S1101` output on the `state` block is asserted when in state `S1101`, since only then is the `Z` output `'1'`.